# Universal point for sky observation

Tags: observational-astronomy

Is there a place on Earth, where polar axis lies on the horizont and heaven equator is in zenit? If it exists, can I, in theory, see all the constelations available worldwide this night?

Comment: The situation you describe occurs any place on the equator, and you can see most of the stars over the course of a night. However, some stars are too close to the Sun, and won't be visible (some will set too soon after sunset, others will rise too soon before sunrise)

Comment: @barrycarter thx, but is the Earth's equator coincide with the celestial one? I thought this point should be somewhere off the equator (actually it should be line not parallel to latitude lines)?

Comment: We define the celestial equator to coincide with the Earth's equator. There is no separate celestial equator. It's just the projection of Earth's equator into space.

Comment: @barrycarter thx, now I got it.

Comment: @blitzar787 You may be aware that the [invariable plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariable_plane) of the solar system is different however. This might be what you were thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

With the axis of rotation of the earth matching the axis of rotation of the stars, and the equator of the earth matching the equator of the stars, any place along the equator would match what you have described. However due to closeness to the horizon, the polar-most stars wouldn't be visible. If you were able to get a hundred metres or so above the ground, with nothing in the surrounding landscape, you could see all of the stars in the sky over a year's time.